# Android Client and Java server, client not receiving message from server using socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server, tcpclient

I am working on project where i need to connect android app to server as of now i am to connect and able to send message from client to server but not server to client.

I tried with BufferedReader and PrintWriter but not help i am using socket programming.

Don't tag this question with duplicate as i saw lots of solution but those for one way client to server not to server to client as well.

I tried many solution but doesn't help any of them so i am guessing there will be something about android app to received message from server that is i am missing.

Need help badly i am out of option so post this question help me guys...

My server code is this

```html
public class SimpleTextServer {

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
    private static String message;
    private static PrintWriter printwriter;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444); // Server socket

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444");
        }

        System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4444");

        while (true) {
            try {

                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept the client connection
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();
                System.out.println(message);

                printwriter = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                printwriter.write("u r dere"+message+"\n"); // write the message to output stream
                printwriter.flush();
                inputStreamReader.close();
            bufferedReader.close();
           printwriter.close()
                clientSocket.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

My android client code is this and i make comment that section which create trouble to me.

public class SlimpleTextClientActivity extends Activity {

```
private Socket client;
private PrintWriter printwriter;
private BufferedReader inFromUser;
//private static ObjectInputStream printreader;
private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
private EditText textField;
private Button button;
private String messsage;
private String message;
ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
ObjectInputStream ois = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slimple_text_client);

    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
    String strdate1 = sdf1.format(c1.getTime());

    messsage=strdate1;

    textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); // reference to the text field
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); // reference to the send button



    SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
    sendMessageTask.execute();
    // Button press event listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            messsage = messsage+textField.getText().toString(); // get the text message on the text field
            textField.setText(""); // Reset the text field to blank
            SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
            sendMessageTask.execute();
        }
    });
}

private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            client = new Socket("10.129.26.120", 4444); // connect to the server
            printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            printwriter.write(messsage); // write the message to output stream
            printwriter.flush();



            /*
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
            bufferedReader.ready();*/





            //message = bufferedReader.readLine();
        //  System.out.println(message);


        //  TextView txtdate1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        //      txtdate1.setText(message);






            printwriter.close();
            bufferedReader.close();
            client.close(); // closing the connection

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return null;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.slimple_text_client, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: readline() expects a line to be sent.  Are you sending one?  Also, I'm pretty sure this is a dup.  Also, what did you find out during your 'I tried many solution' debugging efforts so we don't have to go over stuff you're already done, (in parallel, wasting time).

Comment: First off, does your client connect to the server OK?

Comment: If it does, does it reach the 'printwriter.write(messsage)' line?

Comment: At the server, does the execution reach the 'message = bufferedReader.readLine()'?

Comment: If it does, does it reach the next line after the client connects and sends?

Comment: Also, your var names are very confusing. 'messsage' possesses more esses than message possesses.   Would not 'clientToServerMessage and 'serverToClientMessage' have been better names?

Comment: @martinJames yes my client connect to server and my server also received message from client and i can send multiple msg to server but can't ack from server and sorry for variable name i will make sure in future and in server2client message i put '\n' for readline..